# How to presentModalViewController without dismiss the TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

Hey guys i`m trying to present a modal view controller inside an application with a tab bar controller. The problem is, every time the new view is presented, it on top of my tab bar.

I need to keep my tab bar even when the view is presented. Like google maps application does with his toolbar at the bottom of the screen.

How can i do that?

Thank you

Comment: The tabbar hides only if you specify bottomBar.hidden = YES when pushing the new modalVieController. Could you post the code of your appdelegate where you set the tabbar and the code where you post the new modal view controller?

Comment: This isn't true. A modal view controller isn't pushed onto the navigation stack, and hidesBottomBarWhenPushed only applies in that scenario.

Comment: can i add this effect without using the modal view?

Answer (score 1):

By default, a modal view controller is meant to take up the entire screen (on an iPhone/iPod, at least). Because of this, it covers whatever you have on screen at the time.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller presented via modal segue is meant to live on its own. If you want to keep your Navigation and TabBar, then just use a push segue to present the new ViewController. Remember to use this kind of segue, your presenting controller needs to be part of a UINavigationController already.

Use this to push a ViewController. If it is a UINavigationController it will push its linked RootViewController by itsself.

Create a viewController to push: (Using Storyboard)

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
```

or (Using Code/Nibs)

```
LoginViewController *viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init]; //initWithNibNamed in case you are using nibs.
//in case you want to start a new Navigation: UINavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
```

and push with:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
```

Also, if you are using Storyboards for the segues you can use this to do all the stuff. Remember to set the segue identifier.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushLoginViewController" sender:self]; //Segue needs to exist and to be linked with the performing controller. Only use this if you need to trigger the segue with coder rather than an interface object.

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushLiftDetail"]) {
        [[segue.destinationViewController someMethod:]];
        segue.destinationViewController.someProperty = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh god, i need to look at the dates before answering.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll need to add a UITabBar to the modal view and implement/duplicate the buttons and functionality that your main bar has.  The essence of a modal window is it has total control until it is dismissed.

You might try putting your UITabBarController into a NavBarController, but I'm not certain that this will work.

UITabBarController -> NavBarController -> Modal View